# Centering subtitle under title HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title states, I need to center a subtext under a header. Currently, the subtext is off-centered and lower than I would like [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzqHx.png). How can I adjust the position of the subtitle?

I'm new to web development, so there might be something obvious that I'm missing. See my attempted code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8utW.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMnyt.png).

```css
.masthead {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.masthead h1 {
  color: #F9F1F1;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 108px;
}

.masthead p {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section" style="background-color: #000;">
  <div class="masthead">
    <h1><span>Title</span></h1>
    <p><span>Subtitle</span></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/93dLfaeu/) is the fiddle for this code.

Comment: Share your code here by snippet.

Comment: There is an error in your snippet, the section is not in full height and width, due to `position: absolute;`

Comment: The current version of the snippet does center both lines, so it's not entirely clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your css

```
text-align: center;
```

Comment: If the answers solves your problem please accept this as the answer @Nobetrotter

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the following to your CSS:

```
.masthead p{
    text-align: center;
}
```

The above change in CSS will arrange the subtitle in center, but the following code is what you need I think, I have changed the background of the section, you can change it back to whatever you may need:

```css
.masthead h1 {
  color: #F9F1F1;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 108px;
  margin: 0;
}

.masthead p {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.section {
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="masthead">
    <h1><span>Title</span></h1>
    <p><span>Subtitle</span></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -2):

**please try below css:**

```
.masthead p{
    text-align: center;
}
```